# What's wrong this Code?

Tags: android, mysql, database

```
String query="INSERT INTO ogrenciler(OGR_NO) VALUES(?)";
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginAct.this,dersSec.class);

                try {

                    Connection Conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yoklama","root" , "1234");
                    PreparedStatement PS = (PreparedStatement) Conn.prepareStatement("SELECT OGR_NO,PASS FROM ogrenciler where OGR_NO=? AND PASS=?");
                    PS.setString(1, String.valueOf(ET.getText()));
                    PS.setString(2, String.valueOf(ET.getText()));
                    ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery();
                    if(RS.next()){
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        //ID OR PASS WRONG
                    }
```

I working on Android Studio and MySQL connection without php. I added mysql connector. When I write Connection conn , I got error PrepareStatement its red color. When I fix java.sql.Connection I didn't see any error but can't connection to database

Answer (score 0):

The code in red, you would need to see what the specific error says, but neverhteless, when you run this code in Android, localhost is the Android device not the device where the Mysql database is hosted. So you won't get the connection you are expecting.

If you want to go ahead with this, which I assume is for some test, not for anything in production, you have to replace localhost with the ip of the computer hosting the mysql server which is on the same network that the Android device is connected to (Most likely the WiFi network). And also make sure the mysql server is accepting connections on that interface (not 127.0.0.1 nor localhost) and that the port is accessible through the firewall.

Comment: java.sql.Connection Conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.184:3306/yoklama","root" , "1234");

I tried this one before but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check the rest of the items of my answer?